# Reduce or no gap between a LinearLayout and a ListView in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-linearlayout

I have a `LinearLayout` and a `ListView` in one of the screens. There is a gape between them as in the picture. I want to reduce the gap. How can I do this?
[image: Here is the image.]

EDIT: I post my code also.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#C4C4C4"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.05"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="@string/title"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/checkCon"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="#C4C4C4"
            android:contentDescription="@string/title"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/connect" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="0dp" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your xml layout code also

Comment: check whether you gave any marginTop. if yes, reduce the space

Comment: As already mentioned by others - the 'margin' attribute is used to add space above/below/left/right outside of a UI widget. By default most widgets have a small margin even if you don't specify a value yourself. Setting the margins to "0dp" will remove the margin.

Comment: I got it. The LayoutMargin is ok for all the Views and what I had mistaken is that I have used Preferences to load in the ListView and the Title of the Preferences take some room from the top and I had not defined a Title. After defining the Title I got it covered. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of

```
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
```

in `checkCon` `ImageButton`

Answer (score 0):

you already gave margin bottom in

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.05"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="@string/title"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/checkCon"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="#C4C4C4"
            android:contentDescription="@string/title"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/connect" />
```

remove these margins then it will work

```
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
```

line in text view

```
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
```

line in imageButton
due to these lines your facing problem

copy paste my below code hope it works for you

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#C4C4C4"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.05"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="title"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/checkCon"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="#C4C4C4"
            android:contentDescription="title"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="0dp" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't think so @Android is everything for me. The TextView and the ImageButton are child views and I think the issue is with the parent LinearLayout associated with them and the ListView below it.

Comment: I got it. The LayoutMargin is ok for all the Views and what I had mistaken is that I have used Preferences to load in the ListView and the Title of the Preferences take some room from the top and I had not defined a Title. After defining the Title I got it covered. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" >
    </ListView>
```

Comment: How is that going to remove the gap between the bottom of the LinearLayout and top of the ListView?

Answer (score 0):

For your inner `LinearLayout` (the horizontal one with `android:background="#C4C4C4"`), add...

```
android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
```

Then in your `ListView` add...

```
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
```